# Как занести в массив число и вывести?

Tags: javascript

Есть переменные:

```
var second_massiv = []; 
var а = 45, b = 79
```

Как поместить в массив `second_massiv` числа `а` и `b`, разбив их на 4,5,7,9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var а = 45, b = 79;
var res = (""+a+b).split("").map(Number);
```

Comment: Cпасибо, даже массив не понадобился

Answer (score 0):

## ES6, не надо так делать :)

```
var second_massiv = []; 
var а = 45, b = 79;
second_massiv.push(...[...`${a}`, ...`${b}`].map(Number));
```

Comment: ```const second_massiv = [...`${a}`, ...`${b}`].map(Number)```

Comment: @РоманПарадеев, идея была именно дополнить существующий массив (хотя в примере он и пустой), а так-то да - чтобы создать новый, шаманство с push не нужно.